# AJAX/JSON MVC method not being called

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller

The MVC controller method is not being called with the following code and the issue isn't clear. $("#screeners").val() returns a list of strings:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#submitScreeners").click(function () {

            var selected = $("#screeners").val();

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Applicant/PassScreeners',
                data: "selected=" + JSON.stringify(selected),
                success: function () {
                    $('#result').html('"PassScreeners()" successfully called.');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    $('#result').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Method in controller:

```
public void PassScreeners(List<string> selected)
{
    Session["SelectedApplicants"] = selected.Select(e => Int32.Parse(e.ToString())).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is the "PassScreeners" method in your controller decorated with [HttpPost] or similar?

Comment: It currently is not, but I have tried both with and without.

Comment: What is the HTTP response when you make the request? Is it returning 404, or something else?

Comment: The Session that I'm trying to set in PassScreeners needs to be set in the PassScreeners method.  It is not called and as such, I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the "selected" parameter is being passed in as a null value. I believe this is because you are using an incorrect data format. You tell the server to expect JSON formatted data, but then pass it something more akin to a form value with '='.

Try removing the "selected=" bit from your data line and just pass the stringified list.

If that doesn't work, check the trace and post it. If the string you are posting is just comma separated or something it needs to be an array in order for the POST to work correctly.

Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: This now works in IE and Chrome, but do you have any idea why it wouldn't work Firefox?

Comment: Can you post a trace of the request from fiddler or similar?